# webpack inject manifest into service worker

Tags: webpack, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

In webpack most of my filenames are appended a content hash, e.g. 'app.bfu98y98UB899UHhi9q.js' This presents a problem because in my service worker file i need to add a list of all the filenames that will be cached but all the filenames will not be known until after build. Now, i discovered webpack manifest plugin which emits a json file that contains a list of transformed file names. So i thought great now i can just import the json into my service worker, but then i found out you cannot import json into service workers. So now i am stuck not knowing how to give my service worker the list of hashed file names. I am aware that there are some plugins like the workbox plugin that handle all of this for you but i would like to know how i can accomplish this without such a plugin. Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a custom plugin that emits a javascript file that contains a function that adds all of the output hashed file names into an array. Then i use the the method importScripts(file) (*since regular imports are not allowed in service workers*) present on WorkerGlobalScope to access the function that returns the array with the hashed file names. The custom plugin looks like this:

```
function FilesListPlugin() {}
FilesListPlugin.prototype.apply = compiler => {
  compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync('FileListPlugin', (compilation, callback) => {
    const filelist = Object.keys(compilation.assets).map(fileName => '${fileName}'`);
    compilation.assets['filesList.js'] = {
      source: () => `const getFilesList = () => [${filelist}]`,
      size: () => filelist.length,
    };
    callback();
  });
};
```

then i just imported the plugin into the webpack plugins array and called the file with importScripts('filesList.js') inside the service worker so that the getFilesList() method i created is visible. This is using webpack v.5